# R[x]/(x^4+1) isomorphic to direct sum of complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers, quotient-spaces, ring-isomorphism

I am working on the following problem:

Describe the factorization of $x^4 + 1$ into irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4+1) \cong \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$.

I first found the factorization of $x^4 + 1$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ : $x^4 + 1 = (x^2+1)^2 - 2x^2 = (x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1)(x^2 + \sqrt{2}x -1)$, where these two factors are both irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

I'm struggling with the second part of the question. I learned that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{C}$ : one can think of an element in the former ring as a polynomial $ax + b$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^2 = -1$, so that the map $\phi: \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}: x \mapsto i$ defines an isomorphism. (This way, the polynomial $ax + b$ gets identified with the complex number $ai + b$.)

I tried to use this same logic in showing $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4 + 1) \cong \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$. One can think of an element in the former ring as a polynomial $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^4 = -1$. I'm having trouble defining a map $\phi: \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4 + 1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$ that defines an isomorphism. It seems that $x^2$ should get identified with $i$, but what about $x^3$? How can I identify such a polynomial with a pair of appropriate complex numbers with a clever map?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check your factoring of $x^4 + 1$ again. As David Hill mentions the polynomial $x^2 + 2\sqrt{x} - 1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ which surely doesn't make sense because $x^4 + 1$ has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Moreover, with the correct factoring you can deduce that both quadratic factors are irreducible. In particular, these ideals will be comaximal in which case you can apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get the desired isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4+1)\cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)\oplus\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+\sqrt{2}x-1)\cong\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}.$$
Note that in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)\cong \mathbb{C}$, $x^2\equiv \sqrt{2}x+1$, so $x$ is not mapped to $i$ under the isomorphism. Instead, $x$ is mapped to a root of $x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1$, which are $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1\pm i)$. On the other hand, $x^2+\sqrt{2}x-1$ is not irreducible. It has roots $\frac{-\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{6}}{2}$, so $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+\sqrt{2}x-1)\cong\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments below, the factorization of $x^4+1$ in the post is not correct (I didn't check, yikes!). Instead, $$x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1).$$ Both quadratic factors are irreducible and the roots of $x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1$ are $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1\pm i)$.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^4+1 )= \Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1-\sqrt{2}x)\times \Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1+\sqrt{2}x)=\Bbb{C}^2$